# Players / Teams / Matches / Seasons

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to figure out the best way to solve this 'problem'

I have 4 Custom Post Types:

1. Players
2. Teams
3. Matches
4. Seasons

And i want to connect them to each other somehow so that i can query the results in the frontend.

This is how i want them to be connected:

- Each Season has many Teams
- Each Team has many Players
- Each Match has many Teams & Players

My first attempt was to connect these 4 types with the Relationship Field (Advanced Custom Field).

For example, in a Season's edit page there is:

Repeater Field -> Sub Field (relationship), Sub Field (Points), Sub Field (Games Played)

With the above method, I came across many problems while querying in the front end.

What would be the best method to achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

As per me, just prepare a new taxonomy for all these custom post types. This should be a common taxonomy is for all the four types of custom post types. Now you can relate the posts by categories of that taxonomy...Try it once

Comment: Do you mean i should pick one of the 4 cpt and make it a taxonomy or create a new taxonomy? And how can i link them after that? For example, i want the single-teams.php should pull all the players in that team...